# Detecting a factory reset event

Tags: android

Is there any way for a normal app to listen for a factory reset event and to take some action? I'm looking for something similar to:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
```

The phone cannot be rooted.

Comment: different question title, same question

Comment: Remember that you can factory reset from safe boot and other modes where the full OS isn't active.  There'd be no way to be notified in that case, even if you found some way of doing it when requested through the normal UI.